# C++11 types for variables defined with auto

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book The C++ Programming Language, and in section 3.2.4, he demonstrates a class hierarchy, starting with an abstract class. His code looks something like this:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual Point center()const = 0; //Point is a class defined elsewhere and is unimportant for this question
    virtual void move(Point to) = 0;

    virtual void draw()const = 0;
    virtual void rotate(int angle) = 0;
}

class Circle: public Shape
{
    //overrides functions
}

void rotate_all(vector<Shape*>& v, int angle)
{
    for(auto p:v)
        p->rotate(angle);
}
```

My question is this: what type is the `p` variable when the function `rotate_all` is called with a vector of `Circle` objects? If it was a `Shape`, then wouldn't the objects be sliced into generic `Shape` objects? If it was a `Circle`, then wouldn't the function work only for vectors of `Circle` objects, and not other subclasses of the `Shape` class?

Comment: `auto p` will become `Shape* p`, always. `auto` gets resolved at compile-time only.

Comment: They're `Shape` pointers, but because they're pointers there's no slicing.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ok. They are pointers because the vector is of Shape pointers? And the auto does not need to be auto* for this to happen?

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.

Comment: You put `Shape*` into your *vector* you get `Shape*` out of your vector.

Answer (score 2):

`rotate_all()` is never called with "a vector of `Circle` objects". Its first argument is always a reference to `std::vector<Shape*>`.

The tricky part is, that type of this vector must not necessarily reflect what is stored inside - because you can put into it pointer to **any class, that inherits from `Shape`** (technically/ideologically speaking, this probably should be converted into "**publicly** inherits from `Shape`, but leave that).

Moreover, this vector will **never store** any instance of `Shape`, because it's an abstract class, so its instantiation is forbidden.

So, to illustrate:

```
class Circle: public Shape
{
    //cut
    virtual void draw() const override { printf("Circle!\n"); }
}

//add another class
class Square: public Shape
{
    //cut
    virtual void draw() const override { printf("Square!\n"); }
}

void draw_all(vector<Shape*>& v, int angle)
{
    for(auto p : v)
        p->draw(); //p is an iterator pointing internally to Shape*
}

Shape* c = new Circle();
Shape* s = new Square();

std::vector<Shape*> v;

v.push_back(c);
v.push_back(s);

draw_all(v);
```

Output:

```
Circle!
Square!
```

Simply speaking: `Shape*` is used here to easily introduce polymorphic behaviour for collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

A ranged based for loop will expand from:

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

To

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;  __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

So here the auto variable declared in the for loop is set to the value of the beginning iterator which in your case is a `Shape*`.  Since it is a pointer no slicing will occur otherwise polymorphism would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `value_type` of the container in most cases (or slightly more accurate, the result of dereferencing `begin`) , which for your vector is `Shape*` and so as a pointer, no risk of slicing.

You can also use `auto &p` when you want to iterate something that contains values, but don't want to copy them (because you want to mutate them, performance, no copy-constructor, etc.).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for has more details on exactly what the ranged for loop expands to, and how it determines the range for arrays, classes with a `begin` member and using ADL `begin` otherwise. The actual value type is the result of dereferencing the "iterator", and C++ auto just takes that right hand side type.

As an aside, in Visual Studio 2015 at least (cant remember for others), if you hover over a variable declared auto, it will try to show you the actual type, and some more detail if you hover over "auto" (e.g. it shows me the std::vector typedef).